# Error: Can't access lexical declaration

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, jsctypes, nss

```
let textBytes = ctypes.uint8_t("hello"); 
let a = new SECItem;
a.type = siBuffer;
a.data = textBytes.address();
a.len = textBytes.length;
```

I got ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration textBytes before initialization.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the reference error you are getting, but I think change

```
let textBytes = ctypes.uint8_t("hello");
```

as this throws `TypeError: expected type uint8_t, got "hello"` to

```
let textBytes = ctypes.uint8_t.array()("hello");
```

This will give you a null-terminated string, of length 6. If you want it to be length 5, no null termination then do `let textBytes = ctypes.uint8_t.array(5)("hello");`

as I am thinking, change

```
let a = new SECItem;
```

to

```
let a = SECItem();
```

or `let a = new SECItem();` they are both same.

If that doesn't fix it, please share the structure of `SECItem` and what is `siBuffer`.

Comment: on let textBytes = ctypes.uint8_t.array()("hello"); it throws TypeError: expected type array, got "hello". Add info const siBuffer = 0; const SECItem = ctypes.StructType("SECItem", [
  { "type": SECItemType },
  { "data": ctypes.uint8_t.ptr },
  { "len": ctypes.int }
]);

Comment: Use `unsigned_char` instead, so like this: `let textBytes = ctypes.unsigned_char.array()("hello"); `

Comment: Thanks :)  Any books or reference you recommend regarding jsctypes?

Comment: The best source for js-ctypes is looking at how others did it. I share a ton of snippets on my gists.github i link to them from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Standard_OS_Libraries thats a great page to learn from. Or you can search my gists: https://gist.github.com/search?q=ctypes+%40noitidart and then there are a lots of stuff on github like here are my ctypes repos: https://github.com/search?q=ctypes+%40noitidart&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93 definitely read up on MDN it has lots of good stuff https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes

Comment: I learned best though from others helping me personally, if you need that help join mozilla irc channel for jsctypes: https://client00.chat.mibbit.com/?url=irc%3A%2F%2Firc.mozilla.org%2F%23jsctypes thats the mibbit link or if you have a client: irc://moznet/jsctypes